# How to reset mysqli_result to the beginning?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following piece of code that I am having problems resetting the $row array. It's a nested loop, $row works the first time, then is blank on additional loops.

```
/**Setup local variables with passed data**/
$ing = $this->getVariable('ingredients');
$row = $this->getVariable('unitdrop');
$unit= $this->getVariable('unit');

/**Start Displaying data**/
if (!$ing) {print("No ing");}
else
{while ($i = $ing->fetch_array())
{
/**Display $ing Data**/
    if (!$row) {print("No data row");}
    else
    {while($p = $row->fetch_array())
        {
        /**Display $row Data**/
        } 
    }
reset($row); // <-- Does not reset $row to first record
}
```

Comment: Just checking that you're closing your block comments /* Display $row data */

Comment: Does `$row` return the same data with every loop?  Why not iterate it once and store inside an array?

Comment: @Jamie - Yes the block comment should be closed, my code is different, I am using this as an example, can't share the actual code.

Comment: @mellamokb - Yes $row does return the same data each time. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @mellamokb - I appreciate the suggestion. However I find that option to be more coding then it's worth. Is there not a way to either reset the $row object or return it to the first record rather then creating a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reset` resets an array. **$row** is an object of class `mysqli` in your case. Use the method [mysqli::data_seek](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php) instead (see the example in the link). Should be `$row->data_seek(0);` I guess.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!  
I spent hours last night reading and trying different combinations of reset, unset, close, mysql_data_seek and was going to embark on reprogramming hundreds of lines to change the way my app works.... $row->data_seek(0) worked like a charm! Thank you.