# PHP to reuse mysql result set rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use a query result multiple times.

```
$result=mysql_query("Select field from tables;");

while($result_details = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  { echo $result_details[0]; //Returns 10 Rows..
}
```

but if I use **mysql_fetch_array($result)** again its not returning rows..
I don't want to execute the same query multiple times Please let me know how to use the results of a query multiple times.

Comment: Warning: The `mysql_xxx()` functions have been considered bad practice for a very long time, and are now formally deprecated. If at all possible, you should change your code to use the `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Comment: @Spudley : may i know what is the reason ?

Comment: I suggest you read this: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

First fetch all records using a `while` loop:

```
$result=mysql_query("Select field from tables;");
while($result_details = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $var[]=$result_details;
}
```

Then display all using a `foreach` loop and a single variable `$var` anywhere in the same page where you used query or put query in a functions.php file and include and use anywhere:

```
foreach ($var as $value) {
    $value['field'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to make multiple queries then simply unwind the pointer to the desired position.After you execute your code.You should call function to seek to initial (0) position:

```
$result=mysql_query("Select field from tables;");

    while($result_details = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { echo $result_details[0]; //Returns 10 Rows..
    }
        mysqli_data_seek($result ,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to "rewind" result pointer using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621029/php-reset-mysqli-result

Comment: You meant to say ? mysql_free_result($result);

Comment: No. I meant exactly what I wrote in my answer. `mysql_data_seek()`. If you free your result you'd not be able to do anything with it any more.